# Importing value from JSON array to Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

this may be a syntax question more than anything, but I'm importing JSON into google sheets with the following script:

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Not available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error";  
  }

}
```

And I'm able to get values fine, The syntax for something simple like name from this: `"productinfo": { "name":, "url": }` is just `=IMPORTJSON(urlgoeshere,"productinfo/name")`. But I can't figure out how to get a value inside an array. Let's say for example I was trying to get the front image URL from this:

```
"images": [ {
    "front": "http://front.jpg",
    "back": "http://back.jpg",
    "side": "http://side.jpg"
    } ]
```

I've tried a number of things like `"images/front"`, `"images[0]/front"` but am having no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out, it was purely syntax. ex: `images/0/front`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it was purely syntax. ex: `images/0/front`